# MS Access Disable Right Click on Specific Text Box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2013 and have created a custom right click menu to copy\cut paste (as this is deployed to users using the Runtime and this doesn't exist out of the box).  However, within a form I need to disable the custom right click for one specifc text box - is this possible?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Its ok I worked it out.

For the On Enter event I added:

```
ShortcutMenu = False
```

And for the Lost Focus event I added:

```
ShortcutMenu = True
```